# Github actions stuck on "Starting workflow run"

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have set up a GitHub workflow for my Express.js RESTapi project one month before. I was working fine those days. But now when I try to run the same today it stucks on-screen

> Starting workflow run

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: DEV BUILD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ dev ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ dev ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted 

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 14.x,15.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: rm package-lock.json
    - run: npm i
    - run: pm2 restart app.js
```

What's wrong with this file? Is there a way to see a log file so I can get an idea what's going wrong?

Any help!
Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this issue](https://github.community/t/self-hosted-runner-queued-forever/123937/13), this can be an intermittent issue, link to a [recent (past week) incident](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/dmqsl5g506t5):

> I’m having an issue where all jobs on a schedule are stuck in `Queued : Starting workflow run`.
>
> I’ve checked GitHub status and there was an incident reported today, but marked as resolved. All systems have :white_check_mark:
>
> I cancelled the stuck job and manually tried rerunning a job against a feature branch - same thing.
>
> This was working today and started happening without any code changes (the jobs are on a 4-hour schedule).

So check first if the issue persists over time.

And [the logs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/using-workflow-run-logs#viewing-logs-to-diagnose-failures) (that you can see) might not include much more than "Starting workflow run.".